# BotFrameworkAdapter.ProcessActivityAsync() return null or freezes

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to run ProcessActivityAsync manually (without being via http request).

But when running it returns null or freezes.

I am using EchoBot as an example in the Console

```
var sc = new ServiceCollection();
new Startup().ConfigureServices(sc);
var inject = sc.BuildServiceProvider();

var activity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>("{\"channelData\": {\"clientActivityID\": \"15617619894020.cy8e5xuro9h\"},\"channelId\": \"emulator\",\"conversation\": {\"id\": \"79e62041-99f6-11e9-a11f-bbd34246e3a4|livechat\"},\"entities\": [{\"requiresBotState\": true,\"supportsListening\": true,\"supportsTts\": true,\"type\": \"ClientCapabilities\"}],\"from\": {\"id\": \"5e26d43a-f8ec-485b-9688-091010cb8f88\",\"name\": \"User\",\"role\": \"user\"},\"id\": \"918703e0-99f6-11e9-be13-9b4b2092afdf\",\"localTimestamp\": \"2019-06-28T19:46:29-03:00\",\"locale\": \"en-US\",\"recipient\": {\"id\": \"12fdf550-99e3-11e9-a11f-bbd34246e3a4\",\"name\": \"Bot\",\"role\": \"bot\"},\"serviceUrl\": \"http://localhost:53796\",\"text\": \"Ruda\",\"textFormat\": \"plain\",\"timestamp\": \"2019-06-28T22:46:29.406Z\",\"type\": \"message\"}");

var bot = inject.GetService<IBot>();

var adapter = inject.GetService<IAdapterIntegration>();
var resp = await adapter.ProcessActivityAsync(null, activity, bot.OnTurnAsync, CancellationToken.None);

Console.WriteLine(resp);
```

Comment: I'd like to help but I need more information. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish by running ProcessActivityAsync manually? Are you following a specific sample?